# Getting AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize' while calling method "Access OutbreakLocation data"

Tags: python

I am exploring the Jupiter notebook for Python. While calling this method "Access OutbreakLocation data" I get this exception in Python 3.6:
getting AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'

Any ideas how can we fix this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure to update to Pandas 1.0.3. Pandas prior to version 1 doesn't have json_normalize.

Answer (score 18):

I too had this error, the solution is load pandas of the following way:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

This is due to version change of the pandas library.

Comment: to do the change of pandas 0.24 a 1.0.3. It don´t was the solution for me

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
!pip install --user pandas==1.0.3
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

ibm studio was running a pandas version 0.24.
By using above commands it was upgraded to version 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

for newer versions of pandas >= 1.0.3 importing the json_normalize from pandas.io.json works well and it doesn't throw the error of missing attribute

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 
data = [{"name": "Alice", "age": 30, "city": "New York"},
    {"name": "Bob", "age": 25, "city": "Los Angeles"},
    {"name": "Charlie", "age": 40, "city": "Chicago"},]
json = json_normalize(data)
```